# Need suggestions on how to manage this bootstrap footer for small - med viewports

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on [this site](http://evchargehubchris.azurewebsites.net/Charging-Stations-Map.html), and having issues with how the **footer** displays anywhere below 950 px wide. All the li's drop down below each other to fit into the page, and because of the class "navbar-fixed-bottom" and the set height, it essentially cuts them out and hides them. Our footer is constructed as such:

```
<footer class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom">
<nav>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#datareportsmodal" id="freeDataReports" class="mousePointer"></a></li>
  <li><a id="embedTitle" class="mousePointer"></a></li>
  <li><a id="privacyPolicy" class="mousePointer"></a></li>
  <li><a id="termsUse" class="mousePointer"></a></li>
  <li><a href="https://twitter.com/evchargehub" class="social mousePointer"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/evchargehub" class="social mousePointer"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
 </ul>
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
  <li><a href="http://www.mogiletech.com/">&copy; 2016 Mogile Technologies</a></li>
  <li><a id="opposingLanguage" class="mousePointer"></a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</footer>
```

What would be my best option to maintain a similar height, but include all the items in the footer? Perhaps a collapse nav, or a drop-up or something. And how can I accomplish this? Thanks in advance

Comment: You should either not fix the height of the footer to something rigid (let bootstrap do its work for different screens, use DIV skeleton instead of LI one) or use media queries accordingly

Comment: Bootstrap also has an example of what you want here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-bottom.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you possibly be a little bit more concise ? We have the height set as rigid because it seems that scrolling would be difficult on the map page. That's why I thought it would be wise to try to keep it on one line, or use a dropup or collapse, as mentioned above. If it extends too far above the bottom, the map becomes much less usable, and if it goes below, it's challenging to scroll down there to access it. 

Any other ideas?